# 3 images in a row leaving a gap in mobile

Tags: html, css

the following code works fine on desktop but on a mobile it leaves a gap on the right hand side:

```
ul{
width:100%;
}

li{
width:33.3333333333333%;
float:left;
}

img{
  width:100%;
}

<ul>
  <li><a href="#"><img src="img/men.jpg"/></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><img src="img/women.jpg"/></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><img src="img/kids.jpg"/></a></li>
</ul>
```

I've tried with display:table too but that leaves even more gaps :( any ideaS?

Comment: Don't know if if matters but your image tags aren't properly closed `<img ...>` vs `<img ... />`

Comment: Also, how big is the gap?

Comment: little gap on the right of the last image, that's not the problem I just typed it fast.

Comment: What browser are you using on the mobile?

Comment: Is it some rounding because of the 33.333333333% part? Have you tried adding an infinitely larger number of 3s?

Comment: don't use 3rds like that. do two at 33% and one at 34%, so you do add up to 100% reliably.

Comment: Why not style the `<li>`'s individually. Set the first two to 33% then the last to 34%. If that solves your problem then whatever mobile browser you are using is rounding down. You'll need to change the way you style your elements

Comment: but that way, the image with 34% width has a greater height than the other two..

Answer (score 0):

You should set the widths of the `<li>`'s so they add up to 100. Yours adds up to `99.9999999%`. Style the first two to use `33%` and the last one to use `34%`.

Comment: but that way, the image with 34% width has a greater height than the other two...

Comment: @user1937021 Well set it to `33.333%`, `33.333%` and `33.334%`. Just make sure it adds up to `100%`. Nobody will notice the `0.001%` difference.

Comment: still not convinced you can see a small teeny weeny space still

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `display: block;` on your img tag in css, other things could be the margins and padding not being set to 0 on your ul and li tags.

Have a look at the attached jsfiddle and see if that helps you out with your problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/djy6V/